# File not downloading

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, glassfish-3

I'm having difficulty trying to get my program to use `<p:fileDownload/>`
my button press to trigger it.

```
 <p:commandButton>
    <p:fileDownload value="#{searchBean.currentSearch.file}"/>
 </p:commandButton>
```

my code to download it

```
public StreamedContent getFile() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    InputStream stream =  new FileInputStream(new File(ppath + ".csv"));
    StreamedContent temp = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "download/csv", ppath + ".csv");
    return temp;
}
```

I have checked in debug mode stream is not null and the file does exist. I'm using hosting using glassfish 3.1. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting ajax to false.

```
 <p:commandButton ajax="false">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{searchBean.currentSearch.file}"/>
 </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: it auto removes get and makes first letter lower-case when you use functions in the xhtml with javaee

Comment: Is your server side code triggered when you click the button?.

Comment: yes ajax ="false" did fix it thank you add that to your answer and i'll mark it as correct thank you so much

Comment: Glad I have been of help :)